# Why is Javascript Cookies getting appended although = is being used

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am new to JavaScript, and I am sure someone here can help me with this noobie question.

I read that we can set multiple cookies by the following code:

```
document.cookie = "website=paulund"; 
// cookie is now website=paulund

document.cookie = "secondwebsite=paulund-demo";
// cookie is now website=paulund;secondwebsite=paulund-demo;
```

However, I see that `document.cookie` is just a string object. What is puzzling me is how come the simple assignment operator(= NOT +=) is able to append both cookies together.

Someone please shed some light on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.cookie` is an accessor property with native `setter` and `getter functions`, and consequently is not a data property with a `value`: what you write is not the same as what you read, everything is always mediated by the JavaScript interpreter.

Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)